# Angular: ng-repeat depending on state of other object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use ng-repeat based on the state of objects in different arrays.

Imagine my page displays 3 tables, populated using ng-repeat:

1. A list of persons, with a checkbox thats checked based on an `active` field.
2. A list of messages, showing only the messages for the persons that have `active : true`.
3. A list of statistics about messages aggregated from the second table, showing the number of messages in each category, but should only count messages for the users that have `active : true` state.

An example is shown below. The first table displays all users, with the checkbox for 'anna' unchecked. The second table with messages does not display the messages for 'anna'. The third table shows the number of messages in each category, for messages sent to anyone but anna.

```
$scope.person = [ 
    { id : 1, name : "john", active : true},
    { id : 2, name : "bob", active: true},
    { id : 3, name : "anna", active: false}
]

$scope.messages = [
    { personid: 1, message: "hello", category: "greeting"},
    { personid: 1, message: "hi", category: "greeting"},
    { personid: 2, message: "hello", category: "greeting"},
    { personid: 2, message: "no", category: "denial"},
    { personid: 2, message: "yes", category: "confirmation"},
    { personid: 3, message: "yes", category: "confirmation"}
]

$scope.messagestatistics = [
    { category : "greeting", count : 3},
    { category : "denial", count: 1},
    { category : "confirmation", count: 1}
]
```

The messagestatistics array shown above is generated taking only person 'john' and 'anna' into account.

I've been able to create the first table with ng-repeat, and update the `active` field based on the checkbox that users click. How can I propagate this to the other tables?

What I've tried so far is adding a state to each object in the messages array, that says `active : true/false` based on the state of the person array. Then, every time a user clicks on a checkbox in the first table, I update this state, and regenerate the messagestatistics table. However, I'd be keeping duplicate data with the state field, and am hoping there is a more angular-y way of doing this? I'm also worried this may not be a good approach if I have 10 000 messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue here is mostly how to filter values in a repeat based on some external input? One way to do it is to do just that, [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)! The standard filter in Angular takes an array and filters out only those entries maching a comparator function. You would do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:isActive">
  <span>{{message.message}}</span>
</div>
```

In this case *isActive* is an arbitrary method you define in your controller that takes an object (the message) and returns true or false depending on if it should be shown or not. One thing to note is that filters are run once per item in the array and it can be fired many times in each digest cycle, so keep it lightweight.

For example, don't start looping arrays to check for the active flag inside the filter. Compile a list of active users **outside** the filter and then inside the filter just to a simple check against that list.

[Here is a fiddle with a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/xk81ect7/4/). The last statistics part is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: A note. The watch I added was just a quick way to react to state changes. Using ng-change is probably more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! For the statistics part, I would loop over the messages array, and count them only if the personid is in the currentlyActive array. Now, any time a user is added or removed from the currentlyActive array, I would generate this table from scratch. Would you say this is a good approach? From what I understand, I'm not doing this in any filter function, so this is fairly straightforward?

Comment: Sounds about right yes. The important part is to not do it inside of the filter function, as long as you avoid that you shouldnt have any problems.